# Data in UITableViewCell getting cleared when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

when scrolling TableView, all data get back to default data.
i searched stackoverflow for this problem but i can't solve my problem.
please help me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MTTableViewCell *cell = (MTTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell.mainLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the cell's `mainLabel.text` to `@"u"` whenever the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is called, that's why the data is always being reset upon scroll. In order to combat this, you should be keeping track of the data that's entered into the `UITextField` or `UITextView` and setting that to the `mainLabel.text`.

Following is an example of something that could work, but then it depends on how the cell works, if you provide some additional information, that would help me provide a more complete answer.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MTTableViewCell *cell = (MTTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if ([cell.someTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [cell.mainLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```